django admin warn before page refresh on adding/editing
When I enter some data into Django admin, or when I edit some data, and then refresh the page, the data gets lost without a warning. This is especially annoying on mobile, where refresh is triggered on swipe up.
I want a JavaScript warning "Are you sure you want to refresh the page? Some data might be lost!" Ideally only when something was changed.
The project: https://github.com/Brambor/Jurnal
admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from django.forms import Textarea, RadioSelect, ChoiceField
from django.db import models

from .forms import ColumnCheckboxSelectMultiple
from .models import Done, Entry, Image, Person, ReadAt, Tag


class ImagesInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 0


class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Entry
    ordering = ('-day',)
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField : {"widget": Textarea(attrs={"rows": 1, "cols": 120})},
        models.ManyToManyField : {"widget": ColumnCheckboxSelectMultiple(columns=3)},
#       ChoiceField : {"widget": RadioSelect},
    }
#   choice111 = ChoiceField(widget = RadioSelect, choices = (("T", "T"), ("M", "M")))
    inlines = [ImagesInLine]


class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Image


class ReadAtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ReadAt


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Person


class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Tag


class DoneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Done


admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Done, DoneAdmin)
admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register(ReadAt, ReadAtAdmin)




can u share admin.py?

@Serkan added. Also, link to the project on GitHub.
